# How to share my mp3 collection with my family's android devices?

Tags: music, mp3, file-sharing, mp3-player

I have a collection of CDs that I ripped to mp3 to listen on my android phone. My kids want to listen to some of them on their android phones as well. Is there a way to share my mp3 collection with them so they can also play them on their own android devices? Is there a way to create a family library of mp3s for sharing across all the family's android devices?

Comment: Have you tried with UPnP? Do you want access limited to local network?

Comment: Why the downvote? If you're going to downvote, please give a reason as I don't understand what the problem is

Comment: @Firelord I don't know UPnP, can you give a link to recommended UPnP programs for this issue? I don't mind if access is limited to our local home network or not, but the only people I want to share the mp3 collection with are my kids and my wife and they can access our local home network. Does that answer your question?

Comment: Try something from [here](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists.php?topic=cat;id=79;lang=en). You would need to run a UPnP/DLNA server in your own device and run UPnP/DLNA client on your kids' devices. If the server is setup correctly and devices are in same network, the client would detect the server and make available the collection immediately. I think [BubbleUPnP](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.bubblesoft.android.bubbleupnp&hl=en) has the capability of both server and client.

Comment: Exactly as @Firelord says: *BubbleUPnP* is what you should check first, for both ends. Install it on the device you've stored the MP3 files to, have it scan them and share them. Then install it on the "clients" (your kids' devices), and have them add that "server". Go one step further, install it to another device, and decide what title to play on which device :) // Of course you could also install a "media server" on your computer, *BubbleUPnP can work with that as well.

Answer (score 1):

The first thing that comes to mind is network-based sharing. A common solution is Plex.

Ideally you would install Plex Server on a device that is on 24/7, like a NAS/router/home server. Then install Plex Clients on each device and connect with the Server.  The added advantage is Plex allows connections from over the Internet if you configure it to do so. So you can access the songs from work/school/car etc.

If you don't want to set up the full-time Plex Server, but just share from your phone over LAN, then you can also use the Plex client on your phone to serve the files. But using the client to serve means it is UPnP, so not easily accessible over the Internet. (You can't install Plex Server on Android OS).

TLDR; install Plex clients on all your devices. This solution is not free. If you just want LAN sharing, there are free DLNA apps like bubbleupnp. I personally use a Servers Ultimate server with Ginkgo DLNA clients. Ginkgo is very small if your family just want to consume your content.